# Range selection and copying fixed value (from a cell) in that selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Background**

I have some code which is supposed to copy certain rows from Sheet B into Sheet A based on integer values in cells E1,J1 and I1. E1 has date format. After rows are copied from Sheet B to A, I need to fill column 12 (Column L) with the date from E1 to newly added rows. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15pTVfcoxM2wQTMC-3iLzXVXIEEaZFYXaOf97amy4yRg/edit?usp=sharing

**Problem**

The last three rows of code is not working well. Even though I am trying to select range for same column 12 (column L), it seems to select multiple columns and an additional 2 rows than what I had expected.

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B");
  var aa = sheet.getRange("E1");
  var Date = aa.getValue();
  var aa = sheet.getRange("J1");
  var lastrow = aa.getValue();
  var aa = sheet.getRange("I1");
  var lastrowV = aa.getValue();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastrowV, 11);
  var data = range.getValues();
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B");
  sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, data.length, 11).setValues(data); /* cell J1 gets updated after this*/
  var aa = sheet.getRange("J1");
  var lastrowN = aa.getValue() - 1;
  range = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 12, lastrowN, 12);
  range.activate();
  sheet.getRange(lastrow, 12, lastrowN, 12).setValues(Date);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to give us some values for E1, J1, and I1.

Comment: There are lots of issues with this code, but the reason why it is not running boils down, I think, to Line 12 variable `lastrowN' is not defined. Try that and see how far you get.

Comment: Sorry but even after defining lastrowN, it doesnt work out. E1 - has date values which user can pick, J1 and I1 has integer values which are obtained as "count(A!A:A)+1 and count(B!A:A)+1"

Comment: Welcome. Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You supplied no details about the content of your spreadsheet, data or data layouts, yet you expect a diagnosis of your code. Please edit your question to supply the layout of the data on this spreadsheet (both sheets "A" and "B") and the actual values in cells "E1", "J1" and I1". The code is riddled with problems, but 1) Line 12: variable `lastrowN` is not defined and 2) Line 14: `getRange` is incomplete.

Comment: I forget to add regarding line 14, that `Date` is a single cell yet you use `setValues` (implying multidimensional range).

Comment: _ J1 and I1 has integer values which are obtained as "count(A!A:A)+1 and count(B!A:A)+1"_ So why didn't disclose this in the original question. Plus these are used to define ranges so the actual values are very important. Please, please, read "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: my apologies, i modified the question as well shared the google sheet for your kind review.

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

The OP is attempting to insert a given date in the cell at the end of a row. However, the OP's definition of the range is faulty because it is selecting multiple columns (when only one column is required) and the number of rows is greater (by 2 (two)) than the number required. In addition, regardless of the range height, the OP is attempting to set a single value (rather than an array) into the range.

**Problems**

1) The definition of the datecolumn (Column L) included a value for the number of columns (probably a carry over from having defined the data range earlier).
Old range: `getRange(lastrow,12, lastrowN, 12);`. Delete the last parameter (number of columns) and the code behaves.

2) The code used this method `setValues(Date)` to populate the date column (8 rows in the OP's example data). the problem here is that the value assigned is the single value `Date`. not an array. This was addressed by creating and populating a temporary array `datearray`, and using this to update values in the date column.

3) In addition to the problems noted, the OP code is problematic in that a number of variables names were re-used with entirely different contexts (including "sheet" and "aa"), and some variables were declared multiple times. This made the code hard to read and debug. I took the opportunity to resolve as many of these as possible.

```
function so5473808801() {

  // setup spreadsheet and sheets
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetB = ss.getSheetByName("B");
  var sheetA = ss.getSheetByName("A");

  // define key variables
  // date
  var daterange = sheetB.getRange("E1");
  var datevalue = daterange.getValue();

  // rows on SheetA
  var Arows = sheetB.getRange("I1"); // = 9
  var Alastrow = Arows.getValue();

  // rows on sheet B
  var Brows = sheetB.getRange("J1"); // = 3
  var Blastrow = Brows.getValue();

  // define the data range on Sheet A
  var Adatarange = sheetA.getRange(2, 1, Alastrow, 11);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The defined range on Sheet A is "+Adatarange.getA1Notation());//DEBUG 
  var Adatavals = Adatarange.getValues();

  // define a target range on Sheet B and set values from A
  var targetrange = sheetB.getRange(Blastrow, 1, Adatavals.length, 11);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The target on sheetB  = "+targetrange.getA1Notation()); // DEBUG
  targetrange.setValues(Adatavals);

  // set a range to update date on Sheet B
  var daterows = (Alastrow - 1); // doesn't take 2 row header on B intoi account
  var Bdaterange = sheetB.getRange(Blastrow, 12, daterows);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The date range on sheet B = "+Bdaterange.getA1Notation());

  // create an array to store multiple copies of datevalue
  var datearray = [];
  //populate the array
  for (var i = 0; i < daterows; i++) {
    datearray.push([datevalue]);
  }

  // set the date into Column L
  Bdaterange.setValues(datearray);

}
```